# When it is said an algorithm runs in exponential time, is it meant it has complexity $O(2^n)$, or $2^{O(n)}$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation, notation

Also, are they equivalent or are they different?

Examples of algorithms/Turing Machines that run in complexity of one but not the other would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Beware the abuse of notation; I can not recommend using "$2^{O(n)}$".

That said, a common interpretation is using the placeholder semantic. That is, we read

$\qquad\displaystyle f \in 2^{O(n)} \quad"\iff"\quad \exists\, g \in O(n).\ f \in O(2^{g(n)})$

Compare that to the definition of $O(2^n)$ and you'll quickly see that the two are not the same.

> Because $2^{cn} = (2^c)^n$, the term "$2^{O(n)}$" covers all exponentially bounded functions, i.e. the union of all $O(a^n)$; use $c = \log_2 a$.

Your titular question should answer itself now.

> Since $3^n \not\in O(2^n)$, this Landau class does not cover all exponential function. This is [easy to show](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth) independently of above discussion, by the way.

---

Note how the "definition" makes two $O$ out of one; that's why I think that notation is bad. See also [this related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48527/98) where is becomes clear that even experts don't agree on what the notation should mean here, exactly. [Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30221/98)'s another related question.

Comment: The notation $2^{O(n)}$ is used a lot when the main result is whether or not there exist _single exponential algorithms_.  We've had this discussion before, and I'm not going to be able to convince you, but in my opinion, shared by many researchers in algorithms, the notation $2^{O(n)}$ is quite handy.

Comment: I would read it simpler as 2^O(n) means 2^g(n) where g(n) elem 2^n.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think you have a typo there. Also, *no* O anymore? I don't think that's what people mean, but well.